# Is there a performance issue when using uint8_t on larger architectures

Tags: c++, types

From what I understand, 32-bit and 64-bit architectures(x86) cannot perform operations directly on byte size data but instead need to read the whole word(4 bytes) from memory or cache then shift it around to get the proper byte before actually performing operations on the single byte.

Does this extra data transformation add a noticeable overhead when using small datatypes such as uint8_t or char as apposed to int?

Comment: You could try it an find out for yourself.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "noticeable"

Comment: @Slava If I'm doing thousands of operations using the value, will there be difference in run time?

Comment: @TheBat it depends on many factors, like what operations, what particular CPU what compiler and so on. But in general yes, there is penalty. `int` is supposed to be native type for an architecture and work faster.

Comment: Try after compiling with optimizations, and "if" it is much slower, than do something...

Comment: This kind of question doesn't make sense. Is there a noticable overhead compared to _what_? Using another type? But even if that's viable, you increase your storage use. There's a trade-off. And memory bandwidth is going to cost you something, too; using `int8_t` instead of `int` could even be _faster_.

Comment: @davmac mem bandwidth should be the same, it still has to send the whole word. Unless the processor is smart enough to cache the value AND the zero padding instead of the whole word (I don't think that is usually the case though). Also, when it comes to the speed/space, I'm optimizing for speed, so the mem trade off is fine.

Comment: @TheBat memory bandwidth at the processor level isn't the issue. Consider the level 3 cache. Pulling memory from DRAM is so slow that if you have to pull 1/4 as much then you're going to see a performance improvement. Whether this will be the case depends on data layout etc.

Comment: @TheBat (in other words, _measure it_. If it's not important enough to measure the difference, it's not worth worrying about anyway).

Comment: This question is too broad, as there are too many factors at play. For instance, a "sufficiently smart compiler" could optimise a loop of `uint8_t` accesses to `int`, and unroll or vectorise operations if needed, in which case that unpadded `uint8_t` is on par with padded `int` for speed. We could philosophise and discuss about this, but that wouldn't fit the purpose of this website.

Comment: You could check the `uint_fast8_t` typedef of your standard library implementation. If this typedef is bigger than 8 bits, then your library implenters figured out that bigger data is faster on your architecture. But it's not really conclusive otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Smaller data-types would still need the memory as per the architecture. So a 1-byte variable would still need 4 bytes on call stack for example, for performance and computation reasons. Further, anything in cache line (register/CPU to memory to virtual memory) will not read **just one byte** for you.

(*I am not sure about this statement*) The computation will also be done with word size of processor (32/64 bit), but the outcome will be stored into 8/16/32/64 bit variable, and thus truncation would happen. You shouldn't care about performance for smaller data types.

Comment: One cache line can keep more smaller variables so sometimes it can be more efficient to use smaller data types. I'm talking about arrays

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know both intel and ARM support single byte loads, this means that no extra masking or bit-shifting is required when loading a single byte of data into a register.

So there is no extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform.  Some architectures can always fetch a minimum of 8 bits.  Other architectures are restricted to *word* size fetches only.   There are also hybrids.

IMO, there should be no performance hit whether the platform is fetching 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits.  Usually the data bus is wide enough to fetch the processor's word size with one fetch.

Fetching multiple octets is another matter and there can be optimizations that are platform dependent. For example, a 32-bit architecture can usually fetch 4 bytes at a time, instead of 4 fetches of 8-bits.

**Edit 1:  Memory type matters**
Not only is the processor architecture important, but so is the memory type.  For example, a Flash memory device can be connected via two serial lines.  Any fetches into it would require sending commands via the serial port.

Also, if the memory doesn't support byte fetches, the processor may be limited in fetching a minimal quantity, such as 16-bits.